# Mysql query not working with query having space

Tags: php, mysql

Hi here i am trying to get values from database using query in my php page.
i am getting values from database to dropdown in loop using php.

here is the html of the output

```
<li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Products <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">            
            <li><a href='product-by-category.php?Aviation'>Aviation</a></li><li><a href='product-by-category.php?beauty & personal care'>beauty & personal care</a></li><li><a href='product-by-category.php?Documentary'>Documentary</a></li><li><a href='product-by-category.php?gaming'>gaming</a></li><li><a href='product-by-category.php?health and fitness'>health and fitness</a></li><li><a href='product-by-category.php?health care'>health care</a></li><li><a href='product-by-category.php?hobbies '>hobbies </a></li><li><a href='product-by-category.php?home '>home </a></li><li><a href='product-by-category.php?misc'>misc</a></li><li><a href='product-by-category.php?mobile accessories '>mobile accessories </a></li><li><a href='product-by-category.php?mobiles'>mobiles</a></li><li><a href='product-by-category.php?Music'>Music</a></li><li><a href='product-by-category.php?office '>office </a></li><li><a href='product-by-category.php?photography'>photography</a></li><li><a href='product-by-category.php?sports'>sports</a></li><li><a href='product-by-category.php?tool & hardware '>tool & hardware </a></li>          </ul>
        </li>
```

these values will redirect to page called product-by-category.php with parameter in URL. the parameter will be used to fetch the values from database

when i pass the parameter  for e.x `sports` , i am able to get the results but when i pass `tool & hardware` as parameter i am not able to get the results because of space  and i see `tool%20&%20hardware` in URL as parameter.

how can i solve this

here is query i am using

```
"SELECT product_id, product_name, product_price, product_image_URL FROM product_list WHERE product_publish_status='0' and product_category ='$product_category'";
```

here    `$product_category` is parameter that it will get from url

```
$product_category = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Comment: The query doesn't use the URL parameter, so how can it make a difference?

Comment: Where is your `where clause` in your query to compare your value??

Comment: Use a category number or stricter identifier.

Comment: Your URL parameter should be in the form `name=value`. You don't have a name for the parameter.

Comment: You need to show the code that uses the parameter.

Comment: @Barmar i have updated the post

Comment: How do you set `$product_category`?

Comment: Also show us how you get value from url !!

Comment: have you try with `urldecode()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're accessing `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` directly, you need to do URL decoding:

```
$product_category = urldecode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

But it would be better if you used normal query parameters, e.g.

```
product-by-category.php?category=Aviation
```

Then you could access it with:

```
$product_category = $_GET['category'];
```

Parameters are automatically decoded when they're put into `$_GET`.

Also, the code that creates the URLs should use `urlencode`. Otherwise you'll have problems if there are categories with some special characters like `%` or `+`. It should be like:

```
echo "<li><a href='product-by-category.php?" . urlencode($row['category']) . "'>Aviation</a></li>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.urldecode.php) to decode the encoded string in your query:

Here the link should be:

```
echo "<li><a href='product-by-category.php?category=" . urlencode(Aviation) . "'>Aviation</a></li>";
```

You can access it using `$_GET` php global variable.

```
$product_category = $_GET['category'];
$product_category = mysqli_real_escape_string($product_category); // Addition

"SELECT product_id, product_name, product_price, product_image_URL FROM product_list WHERE product_publish_status='0' and product_category ='".$product_category."'";
```